# How to crop image with different ratio in android?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, imageview

I have an image in an `image-view` which i want to crop in different ratio like 4:3, 1:1, 9:11 etc when we click on the respective buttons.
I am new to this and have no idea about how images are being cropped with this ratios.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Place your `ImageView` inside a `ConstraintLayout`. This will give the ImageView access to `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` where you can specify the desired ratio.

```
           <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
                    app:layout_constrainedWidth="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="183:124"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can also do that programmatically:

```
imageView.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
     dimensionRatio = "183:70"
}
```

Comment: Does it necessary to add other attribute also like app:layout_constrainedHeight and width?

Comment: No, that's optional if you want to specifically constrain only one or other.

Comment: It gives me can't resolve symbol updateLayoutParams

Comment: Your codes work fine if i set the xml attribute but How do i update the image view layout params when i click the button? @Alqueraf

Comment: `updateLayoutParams` is from androidx core kotlin extensions. Please add
`implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0"` to your build.gradle

Comment: Thanks for the help i found the solution.